# Persian Keyboard Windows layout missing

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Does anyone know what to do about this Persian keyboard windows layout? It does not show on elementary os 6. The Persian keyboard I have is another time. Help kindly!

Answer (score 0):

You can add/change the keyboard layout under Settings -> Keyboard -> + -> type Persian...

[image]

If this not solving your issue, can you please tell me more about what are you trying to do?

Cheers!